# Increase image upload limt

Tags: magento-1.7

Whenever I try to upload an Image larger than 125Kb, I receive Upload HTTP Error. How can I increase this limit so I can upload Hi-res images?

Thank you,

FD

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Magento and everything to do with your server settings.

You will likely have to bump up post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in your php.ini

Also, if you're running NGINX you may also have to increase client_max_body_size

Please note, however, that settings and restrictions can vary greatly from one hosting environment to the next. If you're not sure how to alter the config files properly or do not have the necessary access to do so - then you may have to contact your hosting provider and ask them to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have correct permissions for your media dir using command line:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 [magento_root]/media
```

If it doesn't help, try to check your php config:

```
php -i | egrep 'upload_max_filesize|post_max_size|memory_limit'
```

If you see the small values there, you, probably, need to change limits by editing these limits in your php.ini file. You can find this file by running the following command

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Also, do not forget to restart your apache/php servers after some config changes have been made. Usually, you are able to do it by running:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also, I noticed that sometimes mod_security might cause such kind of issues. Try to check your [magento_root]/.htaccess file   for the following configuration and try to add it if it's absent:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

And, the last thing: try to upload images from another browser/computer. Magento has flash uploader for product images and we have cases when the flash player caused the similar issues on some computers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change both post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in the php.ini

And don’t forget to restart your server afterwards.